# Subclass Mess on a vague Binary Tree Question

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, subclass

So, I'm taking data structures and algorithms and I'm trying to answer the following question:

**(20 marks) Exercise 6.7. Create a subclass of BinaryTree whose nodes have fields for storing preorder, post-order, and in-order numbers. Write methods preOrderNumber(), inOrderNumber(), and postOrderNumbers() that assign these numbers correctly. These methods should each run in O(n) time.**

Now... I'm confused about what the question is even asking. Are they asking me to store an array in each Node that records the preOrder, inOrder and postOrder values of the whole tree??? Or are they asking me to create a subclass of Node that contains an integer that's hold the Next value, according to a preOrder, inOrder or postOrder value, relative to the Node we're in...

So, I went with the former and assumed that they wanted the array. But the trouble now is that I've created a new version of Node and I'm trying to call this preOrderNumber() function at the bottom but I get the following error:

[image: Error]

BTNode.h contains the code I used in a previous question to construct a binary tree. It just defines a class Node with a left, right, and parent pointer, as well as an add() function to add new values to the tree, and a preOrderNEXT() function that gets the next value in the tree according to that transversal order. the same is true for inOrderNEXT(), and postOrderNEXT()

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BTNode.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class BinaryTree : public Node {
public:
    vector<int> preOrderNumbers;
    vector<int> inOrderNumbers;
    vector<int> postOrderNumbers;
    BinaryTree(int x);
    ~BinaryTree();
    int preOrderNumber();
    int inOrderNumber();
    int postOrderNumber();
};

BinaryTree::BinaryTree(int x) : Node(x) {}
BinaryTree::~BinaryTree() {}

int BinaryTree::preOrderNumber() {
    Node* next_Node = preOrderNEXT(this);
    while (next_Node != NULL) {
        preOrderNumbers.push_back(next_Node->data);
        next_Node = preOrderNEXT(next_Node);
    }
}

int BinaryTree::inOrderNumber() {
    Node* next_Node = inOrderNEXT(this);
    while (next_Node != NULL) {
        inOrderNumbers.push_back(next_Node->data);
        next_Node = inOrderNEXT(next_Node);
    }
}

int BinaryTree::postOrderNumber() {
    Node* next_Node = postOrderNEXT(this);
    while (next_Node != NULL) {
        postOrderNumbers.push_back(next_Node->data);
        next_Node = postOrderNEXT(next_Node);
    }
}

int main() {
    Node* BinaryT = new BinaryTree(rand() % 1000);
    int arr[] = { 71, 6, 28, 49, 41, 42, 88, 72, 21, 84, 85, 94, 59, 29, 2, 97, 33, 23, 78 };
    cout << "We add these integers, one by one, using a for loop to the binary tree:\n" << endl;
    cout << "[ 60, ";
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])); i++) {
        BinaryT->add(arr[i]);
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    }
    int x = BinaryT->preOrderNumber();
}
```

Comment: If you do not understand a question from your class assignment for "data structures and algorithms", doesn't it make a lot of sense to ask your instructor or teacher what exactly their question means? It's even less clear to everyone on Stackoverflow, who did not took your class and have no specific knowledge of what exactly was taught in your class, and how.

Comment: The right thing to do is ask for clarification from the person who set the task. It is confusingly worded. The term "field" implies a member (_i.e._ data stored on a node). In that case, perhaps it's a node-numbering system they want... Seems quite pointless. I'd lean more towards them wanting a set of _methods_ that are invoked for different tree traversals. The method should accept something like a function pointer or lambda that's invoked at the right time when the node is "visited". You need recursion to get the ordering correct. Your magic "next" functions are not gonna work.

Comment: LOL yea you would think that's the logical way to go right?
Well, I'm taking the class online and Athabasca U. decided to not supply me with anyone to contact so... Yeah. FUN! LOL

Comment: Maybe they're teaching you to deal with what happens in reality where we routinely have to solve problems that have no specification. I would personally avoid storing extra crap in my tree (_i.e._ those vectors). Actual traversal/iteration should not be baked into it. Make a set of general-purpose recursive functions that traverse your tree - one for each ordering type. The caller can provide whatever functionality they want. If they want to output values, they'll send a lambda to do that. Or likewise if they want to push it on a vector, or even something that validates structure.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but that doesn't change the fact that people on Stackoverflow who never took this online class would have even less information about this programming task than someone who at least has access to some kind of class material, as little, or as much, as there is.

Answer (score 1):

OKAY, So yea I think I found out the real crux of this question and I'll answer this here for anyone else stuck in this situation.

The key to making sense out of this question is to visit its location in the textbook. The course coordinator ripped this question out of the textbook and doesn't provide any context. In Pat Morin's book Open Data Structure, An Introduction, on page 149 there's an illustration 6.10.
[image: Pat Morin Book]

So, what this question IS ACTUALLY ASKING you to do is write a subclass for the Binary Tree Nodes such that each Node holds an integer that keeps track of its position within the corresponding traversal type. So maybe your Node would be visited 3rd in preOrder, 4th in an inOrder, and 2nd in a postOrder traversal. So that Node should hold a 3, a 4, and a 2 in the corresponding position. And then you need a function to update that position in O(n) time.